# Getting "Unexpected. Please try again." when doing large join in Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Ok, I have two tables.  Table A has ~60k records and 145 fields.  Table B has ~1k records and 9 fields. I'm doing a join between 23 fields from A to a single field on B.  Each one of these joins is a LEFT OUTER join.  As such, I'm selecting all 145 fields from table A (but replacing the 23 fields from the join).

If I run the joins one-by-one, results are returned in under a second.  However, If I try to run the query with all the joins in place, it runs for hours then errors out with the message:  "Unexpected. Please try again."

This happens if I select one field or all the fields.

Any ideas?

Comment: 145 columns in a table sounds like bad table design. Can you change it?

Comment: Sorry. Due to security concerns, we can't debug code we can't see. Our apologies. Seriously: Questions asking us to debug why it isn't working must include the code. If you can't clean up the query to allow posting it, create dummy data and a query to use for that data that produces the same problem. See [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mvce) for suggestions about how to do so.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  I'm working on creating a more sanitized version of the query I could post.  I understand how hard it is to troubleshoot something without seeing it.

As for the table size, I have no control over it, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Of the first 6 left joins, only 2 are used elsewhere in the query.  Get rid of the unused joins for starters.

Do you have indexes in [medclient.users_table] for all of the fields you are doing the left join on?  If not, then consider at least adding them while this query runs.

Add a few left joins at a time, checking your actual execution plan and see which one(s) kill it.

Comment: This is actually in Google Big Query, so no indices can be created.

I'm not sure I follow on the unused joins.  I see all the join fields used in my SELECT statement.  Maybe the aliases are confusing you?